# Filtering kendo grid column from dropdown

Tags: kendo-ui

I have two values for a column in kendo grid : Part and Subpart, I want to add these 2 values in dropdown and want to filter the grid based on selection of dropdown. I have tried :-

```
{
                                  field: "PartType",
                                  title: "Part Type",
                                  width: 10,
                                  headerAttributes: { style: "text-align:center" },
                                  attributes: { style: "text-align:left" },
                                  filterable: {
                                      cell: {
                                          operator: "contains",
                                          template: function (args) {
                                              // create a DropDownList of unique values (Active)
                                              args.element.kendoDropDownList({
                                                  dataTextField: "PartType",
                                                  dataValueField: "value",
                                                  dataSource: args.Active = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                                                      data: [{ PartType: "Part", value: "Part" }, { PartType: "SubPart", value: "SubPart" }]
                                                  }),
                                                  index: 0,
                                                  optionLabel: {
                                                      PartType: "All",
                                                      value: ""
                                                  },
                                                  valuePrimitive: true

                                              });

                                          }
                                      }
                                  }
                              },
```

Comment: And whats is your issue ?

Comment: when i select a value on dropdown it gives js exception "Unable to get property 'type' of undefined or null reference"

Comment: Wierd cause there is no keyword `type` anywhere in your code.

Comment: can you add in kendo DOJO?

Comment: hmm exactly, forget this code, can anyone please tell me how to filter a kendo column from dropdown having two strings?